# Create a loading page on Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, loading, init, navigator

I have this main dart file

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MainController().init().then((value) {
      if(Version().canUpdate()) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/update');
      }
      MainController().getAccountInfos((datas) {
        if(datas["auth"]) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
        }
        else {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: ColorPalette.primary
      ),
      initialRoute: "/loading",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MainMenuWidget(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginWidget(),
        '/register': (context) => RegisterWidget(),
        '/keys': (context) => KeysPageWidget(),
        '/update': (context) => UpdatePageWidget(),
        '/loading': (context) => LoadingPageWidget(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and I try to display a loading view during app init before change page.

Actually, I have a "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator." error.

I need help please.

Comment: Hi There. what issue are u actually facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Navigator` logic inside `_MyAppState`, `initState()` method - here, your context does not have a defined Navigator, that's basically what the error explains. Navigator context could be accessed only under the `MaterialApp()` (since you define your routes, navigation logic only there).

You can resolve this by moving all the `initState()` logic to the `LoadingPageWidget` - there you could access the Navigator and since it's your default first page, there should be no side effects behind this solution.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will resolve like this

Comment: Great! Do not forget to mark the answer as the correct one if this was helpful.